# Expression for internal struggle

Tags: expressions, translation, idiom-requests, proverb-requests

In German language, there is the beautiful expression "seinen inneren Schweinehund überwinden", which amounts to "to overcome one's inner pig-dog", and vividly describes the feeling of surpassing the barrier of discomfort related to certain things which are good for you in the mid-term, but tedious in the moment. Examples are going running, waking up early, exercising or learning a new language. Another German periphrasis of that kind would be "über seinen eigenen Schatten springen", which is, according to Linguee, "a leopard cannot change its spots". I hope that is helpful.

One wonderful depiction of this expression is done by the German Comic author Flix, [here](http://www.der-flix.de/schoene-toechter.html?blaettern=next&episode=33).

(I am sorry if I should have put this question in the German forum, but I think it would not have been appropriate there, either.)

*Edit: Ideally, the imagery of an external creature or foe that has to be surpassed, or a friend that has to be supported, should remain part of the expression. But I am guessing I ask too much here. ;)*

Comment: You have *"fight/face/overcome your (own) demons"*, but that would be too excessive to describe the examples given.

Comment: I don't know if we have an animal which symbolizes a weak will.  We **triumph over one's self**.

Comment: I've seen it translated as "basic instincts".

Comment: *break one's chains*?

Comment: I don't think English can top "to overcome one's inner pig-dog".  I think we should adopt it.

Comment: overcoming one's inner troll.....and I don't mean internet troll either. It's true that overcoming one's inner pig-dog pretty much takes the cake...:)

Comment: I got a good laugh out of this. Schweinehund is so colorful I'd always assumed it was a family or Pennsylvania Dutch regional phrase, and am happy to see it has a larger life.

Comment: beautiful. sure, that's one way to put it :P

Comment: I am happy I could brighten your days, guys. Thanks for the answers.

You probably will like this one then, too... :)

http://www.der-flix.de/schoene-toechter.html?blaettern=next&episode=33

Comment: Your link above and in your answer are both broken. Just thought you might like to know.

Comment: Much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe I have a possible answer, but it turns the phrase from *subduing* the inner creature to *freeing* it and even *elevating* it:

***Release your inner honey badger***

When you release your inner honeybadger, you throw off your self-doubt and concerns about what other people think. This can be extended to doing things that your hesitant, overly-cautious inner voice tells you can't be done.

This expression is already being used by authors:

[Embracing My Inner Honey Badger](http://smallanswers.us/embracing-my-inner-honey-badger/)

[WSJ: Embrace your inner honey badger](http://online.wsj.com/community/groups/creative-freelancers-307/topics/embrace-your-inner-honey-badger)

Comment: Note that there could be an aspect of this expression that revolves around the premise that you literally don't give a crap about what people think you say or do...

Answer (score 8):

> [***Face your demons***](http://www.usingenglish.com/reference/idioms/face+your+demons.html):
>
> If you face your demons, you confront your fears or something that you have been trying hard to avoid.

[From UsingEnglish.com]

[***Demon***](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/demon) itself is described as *"a ​negative ​feeling that ​causes you to ​worry or ​behave ​badly":*

> She had her demons and, ​later in ​life, they ​drove her to ​drink.

[From Cambridge Dictionaries Online]

The phrase can vary: *fight one's (own) demons, overcome one's (own) demons* or *deal with one's (own) demons* are some options.

Answer (score 3):

I think ***to [bite the bullet](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/bite+the+bullet)*** may fit your context:

> *Sl.* to accept something difficult and try to live with it. *You are just going to have to bite the bullet and make the best of it. Jim bit the bullet and accepted what he knew had to be.*

(The Free Dictionary)

Comment: That is a good start, thanks. Ideally, the imagery of an internal struggle against a personified creature should be kept. Should I mention that in the question?

Comment: @T-Saurus - yes, if that is what you are specifically looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps ***break the back of the beast*** could fit well for  your context. Mostly, *Beast* refers to large, ferocious animals.

> If someone breaks the back of the beast, they succeed in overcoming a major difficulty.

[Source](http://www.learn-english-today.com/idioms/idiom-categories/problems/problems1-achilles-chill.html)

**Usage:**

It took Andy close to two years to finally **break the back of the beast** and become proficient in Japanese.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot think of one idiom that would cover all your demands, but depending on the context:

With an animal

> **[Take the bull by the horns:](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/take--the--bull--by--the--horns)** to attack a difficult or risky problem fearlessly.

With a sense of overcoming a difficult situation in order to achieve something

> [**Grin and bear it:**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/grin-and-bear-it) to exercise forbearance and fortitude; tough it out

With a sense of paying your dues in the form of displeasure (using a character metaphor)

> [**Pay the piper:**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/pay--the--piper) to bear the unfavorable consequences of one's
>   actions or pleasures

Answer (score 1):

For the example refering to "going running, waking up early, exercising or learning a new language", consider **no pain, no gain**.

If the action is deferred again and again, you may "overcome procastination".

Comment: Why an extra answer and not an edit?

Comment: @Mazura - It was an edit ... and I don't know why it generated a second answer :(

Answer (score 0):

I've heard the phrase "monkey brain" used for the baser and less evolved impulses, and especially the phrase "tame the monkey brain" or "tame my monkey brain".

Eg: 
"I have to fight against my monkey brain every morning to get out of the warm bed and go running." 
"I know candy is bad for me but I just can't make my monkey brain understand." 
"I think if I could just tame my monkey brain I'd have fewer problems with anxiety"